# CFA not yielding same results as EFA in R

Tags: psych, r-lavaan, factor-analysis, structural-equation-model

I am using the 'psych' package in R to run EFA. After running the EFA, I use Lavaan to run a CFA using the factor structure from EFA, purely just to humor myself to compare results. After doing so, I am suspicious of results produced by 'psych'.

I am aware that CFA is used to essentially test a hypothesis of how it is believed certain items may factor. And I am aware that the two are not typically ran together. However, it is my understanding that if I am aware of certain factor structure, that results from EFA (RMSEA, TLI, factor loadings, residual variance, etc.) should be approximately similar to results from CFA.

My issue is that sometimes in using 'psych' I can have a 3 factor structure derived from EFA, where all factor loadings appear to be below 1. Then when putting the same factor structure through CFA, I can have a standardized loading exceed 1, and warnings of negative residual variance, thus yielding unreliable estimates.

This is troubling to me, because I feel uneasy reporting results from 'psych'. Especially, because I am dealing with oblique rotation (correlated factors) that can yield factor loadings greater than 1 (say if I use a different number of factors). I have read that factor loadings can exceed 1, if residual variance is non-negative. I am just having a hard time deciphering if I do have negative residual variance, when my EFA is telling me no, but the CFA is telling me yes. Anyone see anything like this previously?

Answer (score 1):

In general there are problems with your model if you find negative residual variances or have any standardized parameter (standardized loading, correlation) that in their absolute value exceed 1 (f.i. see [this review](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/359002369_Heywood_cases_possible_causes_and_solutions)).

### Exploratory factor analysis

EFA has a fundamentally different approach to extracting the factors compared to CFA. EFA essentially extracts the first factor from the correlation matrix that explains the biggest amount of variability in all of your indicators. After that it extracts the next factor orthogonally (= uncorrelated) to the one before, so that now this factor explains the most amount of variability in your indicators, and so on. This way all indicators are always allowed to load on all factors. This solution can then be rotated to create a pattern matrix were each indicator has a "primary" factor that it loads on, but is still allowed to load on all other factors as well. When rotating the (unrotated) factor matrix one can also select that either the factor are now allowed to correlate with each other (oblique rotation) or are still uncorrelated with each other (orthogonal rotation).

### Confirmatory factor analysis

In CFA estimates are created by trying to get the model-implied covariance matrix as close as possible to the observed covariance matrix of your indicators. In these models it is not possible to let all indicators load on all factors (as in EFA) because then the model would not be identified and thus not estimable (or at the very least pretty unstable).

Depending on how you did the CFA in your example you either did not put enough restrictions on your model (e.g. all indicators load on all three factors) in order to get a proper estimate and this resulted in the improper solution (negative residual variances, |standardized estimates| > 1) or you just picked the indicators with the highest loadings in the rotated pattern matrix of your EFA for each factor and thus created an over-identified model. When your model is over-identified you have put restrictions on your model that could potentially not represent your actual data situation well at all and this poor fitting model could also lead to improper solutions.

So to answer your question: It is very likely that the model you tested in the EFA is different from the one you tested in the CFA, which is how you could have a proper solution (no negative residual variances) for the model in EFA but an improper solution for the model in CFA.

PS: If you want to get (nearly) the same result for EFA and CFA simply just extract one factor since these models have no potential for cross-loadings (i.e. allowing them versus setting them to zero).